# Vowels, consonants and Mathematical Shapes

Tags: mathematics, geometry, optimization, letters

Your aim is first to select at least three different [mathematical shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_shapes). For instance, you could select "a losange", "a disk" and "two lines".

You must then ensure that the number of all consonants is exactly twice the number of vowels.

For my previous example, there are

- 2 L,
- 3 S,
- 2 N,
- a G,
- a D,
- a K,
- 2 N,
- a T and
- a W, or 14 consonants

There are also 9 vowels.
We must count the determiners.

14 is not the double of 9, so my previous example is not eligible.

The next part is both easy and necessary for being accepted as an answer: you must draw your shapes in your answer so we can also see them graphically in Puzzling. :)

Finally, the best solution of this puzzle will have, primarily, the lowest number of shapes greater or equal than three, and if two answers with the same number of shapes are given, the answer with the highest number of vowels will be favoured.

Note: your shapes must be in the Wikipedia page, [List of mathematical shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_shapes) or you must explain why it could be added to this page.
Thank you to @samm82 for the reference.

Note: you can't use adjectives to complete your shapes like "enormous square".

Comment: What exactly counts as a "planar shape", and what words must be used to describe it? Without a pre-specified list, it seems like the question will be opinion-based. There are many different ambiguities you'd need to pin down - here are just a few of them: [...]

Comment: Is a "blob" a shape? Is a ["bouba"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouba/kiki_effect) a shape? Is [Albert Einstein](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ0v9.png) a shape (and if so, is just "Einstein" or just "Albert" okay?) What about "an L", the shape of the letter L? Can I make "a big L" instead, or is that not a different shape?

Answer (score 1):

A new solution using Wikipedia's full list of mathematical shapes:

> "A [right strophoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strophoid#The_right_strophoid)", "a fish bladder" (the English translation of the Latin [vesica piscis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vesica_piscis)), and "[a curve of constant width](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_of_constant_width)."
>  This uses three unique planar shapes with 16 vowels and 32 consonants.

"Drawing" them (thanks again Wikipedia Commons):

> [image: a right strophoid, a fish bladder, and a curve of constant width]

**Process**

> I copied-and-pasted the 2D shapes from the Wikipedia page (although I might have missed some) and stored them in a list in Python, prepending "a " to each.  I iterated over them counting the ratio of vowels to consonants and subtracted it from 0.5, so that a value of 0 corresponds to twice as many consonants as vowels, less than zero indicates too many vowels, and so on. I then sorted these results based on this value. Since there were (more than) three shapes that match the desired ratio exactly (ie. with twice as many consonants as vowels), the minimum number of different shapes we need is three, so it's optimal to only pick one of each same shape. No shapes showed up with too many consonants, so there would be no way to counteract shapes with too many vowels, so we have to take all the shapes from this list of shapes with the perfect ratio. I took the shapes with the longest names to maximize the number of vowels.

---

Old solution, depending on what your definition of "shape" is and what synonyms are allowed:

> "A [crescent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crescent)", "a fish bladder", and "[two constructible polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon)", which are polygons that can be made using only a ruler and a pair of compasses (all can be found on [Wikipedia's list of 2D geometric shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_two-dimensional_geometric_shapes)).
>  This uses 4 planar shapes with 15 vowels and 30 consonants.

Drawing the shapes (ie. copy-and-pasting from Wikimedia Commons):

> [image: a crescent, a fish bladder, and two constructible polygons]